# Form within a form for Visual Studio

Tags: html, forms, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing html code in Visual Studio for the first time with C# and I'm a little confused with this beginning `<form id="form1" runat="server">` tag thing. It seems I have to write my code inside of it? Also, if I want to make a form, does that mean I'll have a form inside of a form which isn't really allowed?

What do I do with this. Can I delete it?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="video-container">
<table><tr>
<td class="auto-style1">
</td>
<td><div id="summary"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="auto-style1"><form  method="POST" action="search_results.asp">
```

Comment: you can delete the `#form1`, but you can have just 1 form tag per page, in asp.net web-form

Comment: @MehdiDehghani so whats the point of the form1 thing?

Comment: in asp.net web-form, it's not allowed to having more than one `form tag` per page, so by default when you create new page (add new page), visual studio added some markup for you, including `<form id="form1" runat="server">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can delete that, but if you want to have `postback` via asp.net's controls (such as asp:Button), you should keep that alive. (because web needs form tag).

For more explain:

`ASP.net web-form` dose not allow having more than one `form tag` per page, so by default when you create new page (add new page), visual studio added some markup for you, including `<form id="form1" runat="server">`, so try to re-arrange your page in a way that you have one form tag per page, (again since ASP.NET does not allow having more than one)

You need more form tags per page, go and try `ASP.net MVC` :)

Comment: so basically I can't use the toolbox stuff if I delete that form? Then how would I go about creating a form? Also, if I'm only allowed to use one form is this bad:

<form  method="POST" action="search_results.asp"><input type="text" name="search1" placeholder="Search Here" size="20"><input type="SUBMIT" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></form></td><td><form method="post" action="Default.aspx" ><input type="Submit" name="Clear" value="Clear Filters"></form>

Comment: Do you wanna uing ajax for that search? that block of codes, that you wrote on your comment, is not common when you using asp.net, web-form, I recommended you, keep the `from tag`, and using asp's controls. (for example add a `UserControl` for search and add a `Textbox` and `Button`, then add `OnClick` evet for `Button` and provide the search logic codes, and don't worry about the `form tag`

Comment: I'm unaware how to do that, since my search function is using an API with javascript.

Comment: Do you want to use ajax? or still want to submit the form, but because you don't familiar with asp.net, wrote the code looks like that? if you want to use ajax, you don't need to adding `from tag`, just make a ajax request and get the `JSON` work with it. but if you want to submit the form using `js` (something like $('form').submit(); ), I recommended you stick with asp.net's way to do that.

Comment: Well this program takes information from javascript API and inputs it directly into an sql server database. I'm currently doing this from "javascript->html hidden forms->classic asp->server" If there is a better way to do this I'd love to learn it.

Comment: Please answer me, do you want to use `AJAX`?

Comment: if it is a better way to do what I'm doing, yes.

Comment: It's depended on your skill and your case. I provide some useful link about working with asp.net's controls, hope helps you. http://goo.gl/2Jf1XY, http://goo.gl/gohhLd, this one is great http://goo.gl/hHuOLx,